# Grails in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I'm trying to follow some of the introduction to Grails tutorials and am at the point where I want to try to see if I can use a debugger in Eclipse with my Grails applications. My grails application runs fine when I use the command to execute, but when I tried to use the Eclipse run configuration, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:192)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:200)
at grails.util.GrailsMain.run(GrailsMain.groovy:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1062)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:893)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:744)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:727)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.runScript(InvokerHelper.java:383)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:129)
at grails.util.GrailsMain.main(GrailsMain.groovy)
```

I figure it's a configuration issue (I did recently set the GRAILS_HOME environment variable and that seems to be correct) but that error message doesn't really give me much to go.

Suggestions?

Comment: Use STS (Spring Tool Suite). Step by step instructions for installation (Windows or Linux) + useful intro tutorials can be found here, http://www.grailsexample.net/course-outline/. Follow this and you should be all set. Definitely use the tip on downloading Groovy beforehand; manually specifying the version of groovy to use makes it much easier to upgrade to newer version than letting the IDE do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to get grails to work properly in eclipse. You may want to try Netbeans though the 6.7 version has improved grails support.

Comment: There has to be some way in eclipse. Sts is an option

Answer (score 5):

Grails does work in Eclipse. Based on my observations I would actually say that it is the preferred IDE for Grails development (well the STS version).

A) You could choose to install the Eclipse groovy plug in. Can be a little fiddly http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin

B) Or you could used the Spring tool suite (STS) IDE and install Grails support from the extensions menu. http://grails.org/STS+Integration (Just works!)

STS is built on Eclipse

I personally have found STS to have better Grails support than Netbeans. Its developed by the same organisation that backs Grails

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Groovy Eclipse Plugin?

IIRC, you need this to enable Groovy debugging --- take a look at this page for a step by step about setting up the eclipse debugger - http://www.grails.org/Eclipse+IDE+Integration

But Jared is right, Netbeans step debugger is so much nicer --- http://www.grailsblog.com/archive/show?id=13

Answer (score 1):

Besides grails home, try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Groovy/Grails Tool Suite](http://grails.org/products/ggts) IDE.  It's similar to [Spring Tool Suite (STS)](http://grails.org/STS+Integration) in that it's based on Eclipse, but GGTS comes bundled with the Grails distribution itself and the tooling for Eclipse so that there's no extra step required to get any plugins.